Odd function and differential equation
Let $a > 0$ and consider the interval $I = [-a, a]$. Suppose that $f \in C^2(I)$ is an odd function and that $|f| \in C^2(I)$ with $f(x) \neq 0$ for some $x \in I$. Determine if there exists a linear differential operator $L = D^2 + a_1(x)D + a_0(x)$ on $I$ such that both $f$ and $|f|$ are solutions to the equation $Ly = 0$ on $I$.
$\textbf{My attempt:}$ Since $f$ is an odd function $\left(f(-x)=-f(x)\right.$ ), it implies that $f(0)=0, f^{\prime}(x)$ is even $\left(f^{\prime}(-x)=\right.$ $f^{\prime}(x)$ ), and $f^{\prime \prime}(x)$ is odd $\left(f^{\prime \prime}(-x)=-f^{\prime \prime}(x)\right)$. On the other hand, $|f|$ being even $(|f|(-x)=$ $|f|(x)$ ) implies different symmetry properties.
To find a differential operator $L$ such that both $f$ and $|f|$ are solutions to $L y=0$, I need:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& L f=f^{\prime \prime}+a_1(x) f^{\prime}+a_0(x) f=0 \\
& L|f|=|f|^{\prime \prime}+a_1(x)|f|^{\prime}+a_0(x)|f|=0
\end{aligned}
$$
But I don't know how to proceed. Any help is appreciated in advance.

I think there is even no differential operator $L$ such that $f$ solves $Ly=0$: As you noted $f(0)=0$. Since $|f| \in C^2(I)$ in particular $|f|$ is differentiable in $0$. This forces $f'(0)=0$, since
$$
|f|'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|f(h)|-|f(0)|}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0}{\rm sgn}(h) \left|\frac{f(h)}{h}\right|, 
$$
so
$$
-|f'(0)| =-\lim_{h \to 0-} \left|\frac{f(h)}{h}\right|=|f|'(0)= \lim_{h \to 0+} \left|\frac{f(h)}{h}\right|= |f'(0)|.
$$
If $Lf=0$ for some differential operator $L$ then $f$ would solve the IVP
$$
Ly=y''+a_1(x)y'+a_0(x)y=0, \quad y(0)=y'(0)=0
$$
and by uniqueness $f=0$ on $[-a,a]$, in contradiction to $f(x_0)\not= 0$ for some $x_0 \in [-a,a]$.
